# How do you send JSON data in a rails-ujs Rails.ajax POST call (not using jQuery)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a React client app that needs to talk to a Rails API. I want to use the [rails-ujs](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts) method Rails.ajax. For example:

```
Rails.ajax({
  type: "POST", 
  url: "/things",
  data: mydata,
  success: function(response) {...},
  error: function(response) {...}
})
```

It looks like I can't set `data` to a JSON object like this:

```
mydata = {
 thing: {
  field1: value1,
  field2: value2,
}}
```

I need to convert it to a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type manually like this:

```
mydata = 'thing[field1]=value1&thing[field2]=value2'
```

This is ok for flat data but gets complicated quickly for nested data.

jQuery does the conversion automatically before making a request.

So I'm wondering **if Rails UJS has some automatic way of doing it**, but I couldn't find anything in the docs or code.

Comment: If you are trying to send form elements then `Rails.serializeElement` might help: [rails-ujs/utils/form.coffee](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/utils/form.coffee)

Comment: I got to your post https://learnetto.com/blog/rails-ajax and here too, and I was wondering if you found any more readable solution than formating them manyally?

Answer (score 17):

When using [Rails UJS](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts), data must be formatted as string form parameters. Unfortunately, it's not possible to provide JSON, at least not currently with Rails 6.0.2 (not ideal).

### Solution

Use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to convert JSON to URL paramaters:

```
myData = {
 thing: {
  field1: value1,
  field2: value2,
}}

Rails.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/things",
  data: new URLSearchParams(myData).toString()
})
```

Comment: I get this error `NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "[object Object]":String):`

Comment: @alexventuraio You can't nest the data unfortunately with `URLSearchParams`

Answer (score 9):

Here is my workaround to put/post with Content-Type: application/json.

It works by setting options.data in the beforeSend callback. This way the internal Rails.ajax.createXHR method does not set the Content-Type header first.
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/utils/ajax.coffee#L53

```js
    Rails.ajax({
      url: 'http://some-url.com',
      type: 'put',
      beforeSend(xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')
        // Workaround: add options.data late to avoid Content-Type header to already being set in stone
        // https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/utils/ajax.coffee#L53
        options.data = JSON.stringify(data)
        return true
      },
    });
```

Comment: Had problems with trying to move away from jquery and javascript assets pipeline (move to webpacker) on a new rails 6 application. This was the only one that worked. My old jquery code just used a Get query and couldn't get that to work.Moved to a Post and this worked fine. It was even in a stimulus controller

Comment: holy **, that's still valid for 2022. Couldn't find any other solution to send ajax with rails-ujs

Answer (score 7):

I used ajax call several times and I used to send json data like this.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("jsondata", JSON.stringify(mydata));

$.ajax({
  url: ...
  type :"post",
  data: fd
  success:function(){
  }
})
```

Parsing Json data in ruby controller is easy.
you can just use `JSON.parse(params["jsondata"])`
Hope this works for your case.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed the library code and It doesn't support that because in order to send an object you have to stringify the object, and after doing that I discovered that the library checks if the data is the type of string It changes the content type of the request to **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** .
This [link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/utils/ajax.coffee#L53) shows that condition in the library.
And for that, your option to overcome this issue is to write a method that transforms the object to input form way or use JQuery Ajax or another library.

Comment: Yes, you're right, Ahmed. That's the bit of code I looked at too. I just wondered if there was another place where it pre-processes the data in case I had missed it. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm misunderstanding the issue, but can't you just convert your object using JSON.stringify?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Certainly I can see in the rails-ujs module it's using JSON.parse to parse the Json response

Comment: You're right, I can convert it myself. My question was if there's an inbuilt way in rails-ujs (like in jQuery, see [processData](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)). Also, I'm talking about JSON in the request data, not response.

Comment: I don't think it does, but not sure why that's a massive deal? It's pretty low overhead to JSON.stringify. Or am I not understanding what your trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed no actual solution for the stated problem, just workarounds.

Here is a link to a gist (JS class) that will handle the required serialization:

https://gist.github.com/dansimpson/231546

Answer (score -2):

you can set the content type in your ajax call and sending the data in json format

```
var data={
      user:{
        first_name: firstname,
        last_name: lastname,
        username: username
      }}
```

send the ajax call by placing content type as json in http header request

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://someurl/post",
   data:data,
   contentType: "application/json",
   success: function(data) {
       -------
  }
});​
```

Comment: The OP mentions not jQuery, only RailsUJS library.